# ViewController has no initializers, using core bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, core-bluetooth, initializer

Please don't mark my question as duplicated even if it looks like answered many times.
I really have a problem with "ViewController has no initializers", using CoreBluetooth

I found many similar problems here on stackoverflow (like: Class 'ViewController' has no initializers in swift) but the solution always was unwrapping an optional.

Here I tried to unwrap CBCentralManager object and CBPeripherial object as well but it didn't help. here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you also paste your code directly here.

Comment: You have explicitly unwrapped optional properties therefore you must create an initializer for your class or assign a default value. If you mark them as optional (?) then you don't need to have an initializer

Comment: Hey Abhinav, here's my code: http://pastebin.com/EJ3tLGJn

Comment: Paulw11, I marked as optional as well but it didn't work. I'm not sure how to make an initializer for a ViewController class.

Comment: @Paulw11 Though conceptually the issue is same but I think OP has issue at different part of the code. Can we not allow community to provide answer here?

Comment: @Bart Thank you for sharing the code. Although despite your request, this question have been marked duplicate, here is how you can solve your issue. Your code has one uninitialized param `isOpen`. Change it to `var isOpen: Bool = true` and the compilation error should go away.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much Abhinav! I would have never thought about it! Thanks again!